# Checkbox sign from 3rd party library is not visible

Tags: html, css

I am trying yo use a css library called [pretty checkbox](https://lokesh-coder.github.io/pretty-checkbox/). I both tried direct [link](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pretty-checkbox/2.2.1/pretty.min.css) and npm install like this:

```
bower install pretty-checkbox
```

When I use it on my html, I get this in the UI:

[image]

This is the HTML I use:

```
<div class="pretty o-primary">
  <input type="checkbox"/> 
  <label><i class="mdi mdi-check"></i> Primary</label>
</div>
<div class="pretty o-success">
  <input type="checkbox"/> 
  <label><i class="mdi mdi-check"></i> Success</label>
</div>
<div class="pretty o-warning">
  <input type="checkbox"/> 
  <label><i class="mdi mdi-check"></i> Warning</label>
</div>
<div class="pretty o-info">
  <input type="checkbox"/> 
  <label><i class="mdi mdi-check"></i> Info</label>
</div>
<div class="pretty o-danger">
  <input type="checkbox"/> 
  <label><i class="mdi mdi-check"></i> Danger</label>
</div>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pretty-checkbox/2.2.1/pretty.min.css" />
<!-- works after adding this -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/MaterialDesign-Webfont/1.9.33/css/materialdesignicons.css" />

<div class="pretty o-primary">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <label><i class="mdi mdi-check"></i> Primary</label>
</div>
<div class="pretty o-success">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <label><i class="mdi mdi-check"></i> Success</label>
</div>
<div class="pretty o-warning">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <label><i class="mdi mdi-check"></i> Warning</label>
</div>
<div class="pretty o-info">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <label><i class="mdi mdi-check"></i> Info</label>
</div>
<div class="pretty o-danger">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <label><i class="mdi mdi-check"></i> Danger</label>
</div>
```

Comment: are there any notices / warnings / errors in your console?
do you include other stylesheets / js afterwards? Maybe interfering with the declarations?

Comment: @DasSaffe nothing in the console. I declared my concatnated js after it, and my own css before it.

Comment: @DasSaffe And I can see that I can use styles from pretty.css when I inspect on Chrome tools

Comment: you forget 'materialdesignicons.css'

Comment: @LaljiTadhani It works now thanks

Comment: Please delete the question. It is no longer useful

Comment: Don't delete this. I had this exact same problem and nowhere anyone mentioned using the Material Icons css file. Pretty-checkbox really should be more clear about this in their docs.